# Trouble Logging In Getting Challenge Message

Tags: react-native-instagram-login

I have not been able to get into my account (rahiemshabazz) since May 30th at which time I was met with an error message, "we are sorry something went wrong". I've tried deleting instagram, re-installing, logging-in on different phones, logging-in on separate accounts and switching to my account, etc. None of those seem to work. I've cleared all the history, cookies, and caches from my iPhone, did not help at all.

On my laptop, if I try and go to instagram.com, I am automatically re-directed to instagram.com/challenge, which is a blank page for me, no options, nothing. Again, I've tried cleaning out my history, using incognito widows, cookies, caches, etc. Nothing seems to be working.

I tried deleting the app, reinstalling the app etc. I tried on my apple laptop, iphone and android phone.

"Challenge Message" and "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again".